# How do you make command block output not show up in the console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

## Context:

If you thought [this (a picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qcFp.png) was annoying, wait til' you see this unsurpressable mess:

[image: This is what repeater command blocks do: They spam the console.]

---

## Question:

How do I stop command blocks outputting to the console?
Also, the following command does not work:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

It only suppresses the messages sent to the chat, as demonstrated by the screenshot in the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qcFp.png).
Therefore, **it is not an acceptable answer. Unless you can prove me wrong.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `logAdminCommands` gamerule will prevent logging commands and outputting to the console. The console will no longer show such logged messages (indicated by the "INFO" section), but the console will still show messages from chat (indicated by the "CHAT" section), which the `commandBlockOutput` gamerule controls instead.

```
/gamerule logAdminCommands false
```

As well, the `sendCommandFeedback` gamerule will suppress messages sent to the player's chat if they run commands themselves:

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```